# Change widgets ImageButton drawable from a service

Tags: android

I have a widget for my app, it is a simple toggle widget, when i press it it runs a service.
The service does all the work and enables isRunning= true;

when isRunning is true i'd like the ImageButton to have drawable_enabled.png

and when i stop the service (it can be stopped with the widget, from the app or from the notification) it should change it's drawable to drawable_disabled.png

Everything is working fine but i can't figure out how to change the drawable from the service

Answer (score 0):

You can send Intent to your widget. `AppWidgetProvider` has `onReceive` method, which you should override.